# How to distribute API access rules for Eclipse with my library?

Tags: java, eclipse, api

Eclipse knows access rules for libraries you use in your project (which packages/classes may be called and which shall display an error). You can manually define these rules via project settings, but for some libraries like JRE etc., Eclipse seems to know already some access rules.

From where does it know? Are these access rules located somewhere in Eclipse itself, or are they part of the library, e.g. JRE/lib?

I want to support users of my library with pre-defined access rules for its API, but don't know where I can specify them. Does anybody know?